# MonoTouch missing members?

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, catransform3d

I'm just converting an objc video player sample to MonoTouch and came to this part:

```
self.view.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakePerspective(1000);
```

In Monotouch, I can do a 'scale' or 'rotate' transform:

```
this.View.Layer.SublayerTransform = CATransform3D.MakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

But no perspective option is visible even after searching in the object browser equivalent.  Is this part of the 'curation' of API's I read about somewhere, where less used items aren't brought through to MonoTouch ?

How would I use this function?  Is it common for members to be missing in this way?  I thought an automated tool generated the bindings so I was figuring all the elements would be available unless redundant or deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a function named `CATransform3DMakePerspective` in Apple documentation web site (nor did grepping the Apple SDK headers files returned it).

*note: please edit your post if you have an URL pointing to it's documentation*

A bit of googling [returned a macro](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/ios-perspective-transform):

```
#define CATransform3DMakePerspective(x, y) (CATransform3DPerspective(CATransform3DIdentity, x, y))
```

that depends on another macro `CATransform3DPerspective` and a C function `CATransform3DMake`. Each of them looks trivial to port to C#.

This **might** not be identical to the ObjC sample you're porting. OTOH the code of your video player should include similar functions that you can translate into C#.

Comment: Thankyou very much poupou!  You are right - I hadn't seen macros like that before, and have much to learn about objc.  The example had come from a coreanimation demo - apologies for not providing the link - https://github.com/tapharmonic/Core-Animation-Demos.  As you suggested there is another file there (CoreAnimation_Prefix.pch) with this method in it.  Much appreciated :)